# Storing HTML in MySQL: blob or text?

Tags: mysql

I have to store large amount of HTML data in a database .

I have Googled and found something about the `blob` datatype, I checked it and it is working correctly.

I need to store the HTML pages in the tables and need to show them correctly as web pages on demand.

So, which is better for storing large HTML pages, `text` or `blob`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd use `blob` it's a varbinary and does not do any translation. So your html will come out exactly the same way that it went in.

If you want to search and index that html `TEXT` may be a better choice. 
In that case make sure you use the proper charset.
I'd recommend UTF8.

Comment: @DileepDil, John -> Johan, performance difference is too small to matter, you worry too much.

Comment: heheh ok Johan Bro ,i am littlebit newbie here thats why. :D

Answer (score 1):

Seven years have passed since this question was asked.  The database industry is converging on using UTF-8 for all text.

If you use `TEXT` and make it `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, and you do likewise for all other text fields (except postal_code, country_code, hex, and a few other that are defined to be ascii), then `TEXT` makes sense.

But, there is another consideration.  If your HTML is an entire page, it makes good sense to put that in a file, not a database table.  That way, it can be fetched directly by HTTP.  Similarly images and `BLOB` lead to a argument for `<img src=...>` where `...` is the url of a `.jpg` *file*.