# Saving HTML data in a field using BLOB or TEXT/CLOB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, blob

I need to **store a page of html data** in a field called ProjectDescription in mySQL database using Spring & JPA 2.1 . I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7626585/6043669)  and all other questions with BLOB tag, but need some clarity on why the fields are saving in a certain manner in my db. I have created the fields in the manner below using both String and byte[] field types.

**Method1**: Saving data as TEXT (After encoding in Base64 format I save my html data as String using the below method)

```
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
@Lob
private String projectDescription = "";
```

**Method2**: Saving data as binary using BLOB

```
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Lob
@Column(length=5000)
private byte[]  projectDescription1 =new byte[0];
```

My assumptions:
I assume that since a page of html data is not very large, TEXT is ok as comapred to BLOB

I tested both and the fields are saved as below in mySQL database

> In **Method1:**
>
> 1. Type: TEXT
> 2. DisplaySize is constantly 1431655765.
>
> This size doesn't change irrespective of my @Column(length=5000)
> annotaton.
>
> In **Method2**
>
> 1. Type: BLOB
> 2. DisplaySize: -1

**Question1:** What is the source of this DisplaySize ? This seems quite large in case of TEXT and very small(-1) in case of byte[] field type. Why doesn't @Column length seem to change change the DisplaySize.

**Question2:** Is it ok to store HTML data as String field type(eventually as TEXT) as opposed to byte[] (eventually as a blob)?

Note: I have read all the questions with BLOB tags and am clear that images/documents need to be saved as BLOB and text as as CLOB/TEXT. However, would like to confirm again for HTML data given how large DisplaySize is allocated in DB for TEXT.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you seeing these `DisplaySize` values?  Whilst MySQL numeric types can have a "display width" [attribute](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/numeric-type-attributes.html), string types either have an explicit or implicit "maximum length"—but this would not normally be referred to as `DisplaySize`.  Furthermore, the value of 1431655765, which is 0x55555555, is very strange indeed... it equals 2^32/3, and therefore represents the maximum number of 3-byte-characters that can be stored in a `LONGTEXT` column... not sure what use that is to anyone.

Comment: I see DisplaySize in fieldTypes while using MySQL Workbench. Yes, it seems strange indeed.

Comment: MySql WorkBench has a lot of bugs, make your checks with another client like hidesql, sqlyog, phpmyadmin... Because -1 for blob looks like a overflow in workbench, and post the create table statements because they can tell a lot more. And about display size  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/370  . I still

Comment: And unless you are compressing the data, save text as text to preserve the critical encoding information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a whole page, why go through the extra layer of fetching from a database table?  If it is only part of a page, then I recommend `TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  Any non-UTF-8 text in the page will cause trouble; may as well catch it early.

And the database industry is converging on using UTF-8 for all text.

Base64 is 8/6 times as big.  And all it is doing is avoiding trouble with non-UTF-8 characters that *should not be there*.  If anything, compress it in the client and store in a `BLOB`, thereby shrinking 3/1.

In MySQL, `TEXT` is 64K *bytes*.  You might be better off with `MEDIUMTEXT`, which has a limit of 16MB.  I say "bytes" because, for example, Chinese needs 3, sometimes 4, *bytes* per *character*, so only about 25K characters of Chinese text will fit in `TEXT`.

"DisplaySize is constantly 1431655765" -- What???  A gigabyte for a web page; no way!  Even if that includes images (which it should not), that is quite unreasonable.  *Edit: eggyal's Comment on 2^32/3 probably explains this odd number.*

In MySQL, `SELECT length(my_text) ...` will get the number of *bytes* in that column.

Comment: I now understand that UTF-8 doesn't accept european characters. So in that case Base64 encoding is the only way out isn't it. Also, why is Base64 encoding 6/8 times bigger?

Comment: @HopeKing - What?  UTF-8 handles all European characters, and all characters of all established languages worldwide.  Accented European letters will not fit in _Ascii_, which has only 7 bits.  Base64 juggles _bits_ to take any 8-bit bytes and display them in ascii.  But you can no longer read even plain English.